# Adding a Doughnut plot using Vue.js 3 to a Django template

Tags: django, vuejs3, vue-component

I want to display a Doughnut plot in a Django template using Vue.js 3. The Doughnut plot will be a component because I need to reuse this plot a lot.

So far I have managed to create a simple text component in this way:

base.html

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
{% block vue %}
{% endblock %}
```

status.html

```
{% extends "../base.html" %}
{% load static %}
<doughnut-plot title={{title}}></doughnut-plot>
{% block vue %}
<script type="module" src="{% static 'js/status.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

status.js

```
import DoughnutPlot from "./components/doughnut_plot.js"

const app_status = Vue.createApp({
    components: {
        DoughnutPlot,
    }
});
app_status.mount("#app_status");
```

doughnut_plot.js

```
export default {
    props: ['title'],
    template: `<h4>{{title}}</h4>`
};
```

This code show the correct title that I pass with the context in the corresponding view.

However, I cannot manage to change doughnut_plot.js into a plot.

I tried the following:

status.html

```
% block vue %}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<!-- Include Vue Chart.js wrapper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-chartjs@3"></script>
<!-- Include your Vue component script -->
<script type="module" src="{% static 'js/components/doughnut_plot.js' %}"></script>
<script type="module" src="{% static 'js/status.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

doughnut-plot.js

```
import { Doughnut } from 'vue-chartjs';

export default {
    extends: Doughnut,
    props: ['data', 'options'],
    mounted() {
        this.renderChart(this.data, this.options);
    }
};
```

But I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue-chartjs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".` And I cannot manage to solve it.

Any help will be greatly aprecciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by removing `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-chartjs@3"></script>`, and directly importing from the absolute url in doughnut-plot.js:

```
import { Doughnut } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-chartjs@3';
```

You might still run into some problems, because I'm not sure if chart.js is in scope when run from a module script file.

My guess is that you lifted this from a tutorial that uses some kind of packager (e.g. webpack) to create a precompiled main.js file instead of manually including dependencies in your project.

I would advise you to think about packaging your JS assets if your project grows, because loading your JS with separate script tags for all your dependencies can become complicated pretty quickly.

Let me know if you need help with that or check out this link: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#inspecting-the-project-s-webpack-config

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this but did not work. The error is related to vue-chartjs. In the end I could not manage to make vue-chartjs work, So I am ditching the component part and creating the charts directly in status.js.